# Транспорт для бэкенда на NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, wcf, signalr, .net

Как известно, WCF полноценно не поддерживается в Net Core/Standart, серверной части нет, а при использовании клиентов standart при подключении к сервисам на framework могут возникать различные проблемы, которые приводят к дедлокам и прочим неприятным вещам. ( например, нельзя настроить ConcurrencyMode для CallBackBehavior)

Изучая матчасть, заметил, что везде советуют использовать signalR. Но возникает вопрос, насколько он производителен? TCP он не поддерживает, http априори медленнее, а требования к производительности у нас достаточно высоки.

Какой транспорт вместо WCF сейчас(2020 г.) лучше использовать в рамках Net Core для взаимодействия бэк сервисов с требованием высокой пропускной способности? Или же теперь остается возможность использования только внешних брокеров сообщений?

Comment: [Общие сведения об использовании gRPC на платформе .NET Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/grpc/?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: Спасибо. Насколько я понял, основных варианта 2:signalR и gRPC. Надо бенчмаркать.

Comment: `SignalR` - это скорее о взаимодействии в реальном времени сервера и клиентского браузера, нужно для чатов, групповых онлайн-игр и т.п.

Comment: Насколько я понял, сейчас signalR не привязан конкретно к браузеру, а выступает именно полноценным транспортом(можно использовать на бэке). Или там есть какие-то сильные привязки в WEB?

Comment: На это вопрос, к сожалению, я не возьмусь ответить, т.к. не работал на практике с SignalR. Кстати, до конца апреля можно еще успеть бесплатно зарегистрироваться и посмотреть курсы на `Pluralsight`, вот рекомендую [Using gRPC in ASP.NET Core](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/aspnet-core-grpc/table-of-contents)

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SignalR` - это по сути обертка над несколькими протоколами, в приоритете `WebSocket`, если он не доступен, то `Long polling` и другие протоколы. Он неплох для `Real Time` веб приложений. Если требуется обычное синхронное взаимодействие между сервисами, то можно использовать обычный `REST`, принципе `ASP.NET Core` сейчас довольно быстр. Если нужно асинхронное взаимодействие, то `Kafka`, `NATS` или любой другой стриминг сообщений. Ну а если этого не достаточно (сначала следует дойти до таких нагрузок). То искать что-то специфичное. Для многих задач, например финансовых, есть свои протоколы, которые подходят только для этих задач, но из-за этого они быстрее остальных.